# Is Dragons Rescue Riders set in the same universe as the previous How to Train Your Dragon cartoons and films?

Tags: how-to-train-your-dragon

Is there any evidence in the new Netflix Dragons Rescue Riders cartoon to indicate whether or not it exists in the same continuity as the previous How To Train Your Dragon films and cartoons? And if it is where it sits within the timescale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's inspired by the same books (and the art style is directly related to films and TV series), but it's **not canon with the main series of films and TV shows**, according to Executive Producer Jack Thomas and Co-Executive Producer Brian K. Roberts.

> **Jack Thomas:** *The idea was to take the world and the DNA of the franchise and create a new type of storytelling aimed at a younger audience. **That’s why it’s all new characters and all new locations, so that we could make it its own thing.***
>
> **Jackson Murphy:** *And what elements did you take from the movies and the other TV series and incorporate into the new show?*
>
> **Brian K. Roberts:** *We looked at a lot of the visuals from the movies and from “Race to the Edge” and other TV series and looked at ways that we could interpret that into a brighter, more chunky and a little younger-skewing visual… **We created a world that felt younger, while still keying off of some of the same inspirations as the original films.***
>
> ...
>
> **JT:** *I would say this: if you’re a fan of the franchise, and if you watch carefully, you will see Easter Eggs. But I’m not going to give you clues on where they are or what they are. (laughs) I love the main franchise. I did 78 episodes of “Race to the Edge” and before that “Defenders of Berk”. **It’s really important to me that we fit in even though we are a very different aspect of the main franchise. So there are references.***
>
> <sub><sup>[INTERVIEW: “Dragons: Rescue Riders” EP Jack Thomas and Co-EP Brian K. Roberts](http://www.animationscoop.com/interview-dragons-rescue-riders-ep-jack-thomas-and-co-ep-brian-k-roberts/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I do not see how the quote supports the answer of not canon.  In fact new characters in new locations to me says they want the old stuff considered canon.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I fail to see how you could take "*so that we could make it its own thing*" in any other way than it being a different level canon

Comment: If ST:Voyager is set on the other side of the galaxy to minimize interacting with TNG and DS9 stories doesn't make it a different canon. The first and especially last things you bolded indicate effort to coexist with the main canon and respectfully still seem to support the opposite of your answer.  I'd ask for some fact in one show that is contradicted by a fact in another to split the canons. Like Real Ghostbusters vs Ghostbusters II or Thunderball vs Never Say Never Again can't coexist. Alternatively Ewoks animated can exist in Star Wars of the 1980s but targets younger fans.

Comment: @lucasbachmann - I think you're clutching at straws to try to disprove what seems to me to be a fairly conclusive answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is in the same universe.
[This article about Netflix announcing it](https://www.animationmagazine.net/streaming/netflix-slates-7-preschool-originals-from-award-winning-creators/) states this (emphasis mine):

> DreamWorks Dragons Rescue Riders (2019) is a CG animated comedy adventure series that **opens a brand new chapter in DreamWorks Animation’s Academy Award-nominated and Golden Globe-winning How to Train Your Dragon franchise.**

Wikipedia’s article about it also states that it is in the same world/franchise repeatedly.

I do not know about the timeline. Searching online finds nothing about it, but people who’ve seen it might know more.

Comment: I may be mistaken but my understanding is that being the same franchise does not necessarily mean being in the same universe or continuity.

Answer (score -2):

In (golden dragon) a easter egg  in final riddle notice the dragon in the wall. they are main dragon on (httyd) because hiccup draw the map.

Comment: An Easter Egg does not make something the same universe. Also you should provide evidence for this I.e. a screenshot. You can [edit] your answer to include this.